# High response time because of GC in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection

I have a spring boot application which I'm running inside docker containers in an openshift cluster. In steady state, there are N instances of the application (say N=5) and requests are load balanced to these N instances. Everything runs fine and response time is low (~5ms with total throughput of ~60k).

Whenever I add a new instance, response time goes up briefly (upto ~70ms) and then comes back to normal.

I checked NewRelic JVM stats.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, whenever the app starts, there is GC-MarkSweep which I think is probably related to the initial high response time.

How can I avoid this? I'm using Java 8. Will using a different GC (G1) help or can I somehow tune my GC settings?

Comment: The JVM Is warming up?

Answer (score 0):

JVM itself requires quite a work when starting, and Spring Boot is also adding a lot of it's own work and classes. Try to remove/switch off all unused features, since autoconfiguration magic can cause a lot of unnecessary overhead.